# String concatenation off dataframe columns as a series index

Tags: pandas

**Question**

How do I create a Pandas Series from the `"Cluster Mean"` column of this dataframe but use the data from `monthly`, `weekly` and `daily` columns as the series index.

**Desired output** of the series would be like this with a string concatenation off all columns + df index as the index and "Cluster Mean" column as the value. :

```
0_[1.0765, 3, monthly]_[1.0755, 2, weekly]_1  1.0760
1_[1.0592, 6, monthly]_[1.058, 12, weekly]_1  1.0586
2_[1.0461, 3, monthly]_[1.0459, 24, weekly]_1 1.0460
```

**Screenshot** of the original dataframe:

[image: df shot]

**Data** (Minimal, Reproducible Example)

```
{'monthly': {0: [1.0765, '3', 'monthly'],
  1: [1.0592, '6', 'monthly'],
  2: [1.0461, '3', 'monthly']},
 'weekly': {0: [1.0755, '2', 'weekly'],
  1: [1.058, '12', 'weekly'],
  2: [1.0459, '24', 'weekly']},
 'daily': {0: '', 1: '', 2: ''},
 'Cluster Mean': {0: 1.076, 1: 1.0586, 2: 1.046}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

you can make use of `apply()` method and `join()` method:

```
idx=df.index.astype(str)+'_'+df.apply(lambda x:'_'.join((str(x['monthly']),str(x['weekly']),str(x['daily']))),1)

val=df['Cluster Mean']
```

**Note:** In the above code idx variable is storing your index values and val variable storing your values for that index

Finally make use of `Series()` method:

```
result=pd.Series(index=idx,data=val.values.tolist())
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output(Series):

```
#output
0_[1.0765, '3', 'monthly']_[1.0755, '2', 'weekly']_1     1.0760
1_[1.0592, '6', 'monthly']_[1.058, '12', 'weekly']_1     1.0586
2_[1.0461, '3', 'monthly']_[1.0459, '24', 'weekly']_1    1.0460
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access row index in [pandas.DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `row.name` if axis is `1`.

After joined row values, you can create a new dataframe from Series with [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```py
def join_row(row):
    cols = [row.name] + row[['monthly', 'weekly', 'daily']].values.tolist()
    return '_'.join(map(str, cols))

result = pd.concat([df.apply(join_row, axis=1), df['Cluster Mean']], axis=1)
```

```
# print(result)

                                                   0  Cluster Mean
0_[1.0765, '3', 'monthly']_[1.0755, '2', 'weekly']_1     1.0760
1_[1.0592, '6', 'monthly']_[1.058, '12', 'weekly']_1     1.0586
2_[1.0461, '3', 'monthly']_[1.0459, '24', 'weekly']_1    1.0460
```